# how to access c++ global variable modified by public class function in c file

Tags: c++, variables, global

```
DialogReprog.cpp

unsigned char PasswordValue[16];
unsigned char SystemKeyValue[16];

void CDialogReprog::OnOK()
{
// TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
char *ptr;
size_t count=0;

UpdateData();
TCHAR buffer[50];
GetDlgItemText(IDC_PASSWORD, buffer, 50);
ptr = (char *)buffer;
for(count = 2; count < 6; count++)
{
    sscanf(ptr, "%2hhx",&PasswordValue[count-2]);
    ptr += 2;
}

GetDlgItemText(IDC_SYSKEY, buffer, 50);
ptr = (char *)buffer;
for(count = 2; count < 18; count++)
{
    sscanf(ptr, "%2hhx",&SystemKeyValue[count-2]);
    ptr += 2;
}

UpdateData(FALSE);
CDialog::OnOK();

}
```

Need to access the PasswordValue byte array in C file to access the data, when i debug i can see the data is visible in the watch window(i am using Visual Studio 2005 for my Project)

Comment: Do you mean a C language source file or a C++ language source file? It wasn't clear to me.

Comment: Not totally sure what the question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access things from C++ code in C code, you need to understand a bit one major difference between the languages when it comes to compiling and linking. Every language uses [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). This means that the same variable/function will have different names for the linker depending if you create it in C or C++. This is also why you can overload functions in C++ but not in C.

When it comes to fixing your problem, the commonly accepted and most simple solution is to declare this variables as if they use the C-style mangling. To do that you simply need to use `extern "C"` like this:

```
extern "C"{
    unsigned char PasswordValue[16];
    unsigned char SystemKeyValue[16];
}
```

In this case you will be able to access these variables from a C file.

This works the same for functions as well, however that also means you cannot use the C++ features like overloading with these names (if you try to your linker will complain).